# FactoryGirl and Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have two classes and two factories:

```
class User
 belongs_to :company
end

class Company
 has_many :users
end

Factory.define :user do |u|
 u.name "Max"
 u.association :company
end

Factory.define :user2, :parent => :user do |u|
 u.name "Peter"
end

Factory.define :company do |c|
 c.name "Acme Corporation"
end
```

How can I achieve having both users in the same company? When running the tests, FactoryGirl creates two company records but I want both users to be connected to one record.

Any hints?

Comment: I think you are using FactoryGirl as a direct fixtures substitute. The only difference between your users is the name. Factories are for creating new users without having to specify everything. Please, take a look at [Getting Started](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

Comment: There could be more differences. This is just an example, the real code looks different. Nonetheless, thanks for your help. I am a bit slow today ... ;-)

Comment: I found myself translating fixtures into factories when I moved to FactoryGirl, so I thought that it may be worth noting.

Comment: I am using FactoryGirl for a while, but I am regularly confused about the way associated objects are initialized ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@company = Factory.create :company
@first_user = Factory.create :user, :company => @company
@second_user = Factory.create :user, :company => @company
```

Something like that should do, but please, read my comment first, I think you got the wrong idea about Factory Girl.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
user1 = Factory(:user)
user2 = Factory(:user2, :company => user1.company)
```